# Compliance Mode and overriden methods

Tags: java

I have a question about the compliance mode.
What happens with my class which extends a basic java class, for example Properties and is compiled with JDK5 and packaged into a jar. Now I use this jar in a project which gets build with JDK 6 but in compliance mode 5.
Can someone now use the new method stringPropertyNames() - which is new in JDK6 - on my class in the JDK6 project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, **as long as you run your project on JRE 6 JVM**. And you don't need your project to be compiled with compliance to Java 1.5. That is, when compiling your project, you don't need to use either `-source 1.5` nor `-target 1.5` options.

On the other hand, when running you project on JRE 5 JVM, it will fail with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:B.stringPropertyNames()Ljava/util/Set;
```

regardless of the options used on compilation of your project.

What happens in runtime, is that the JVM searches corresponding execution bytecode for `Properties.stringPropertyNames()`. When running on JRE 6, such code exists (no matter what options were used in compilation). When running on JRE 5, it doesn't exist.

I checked the scenario you suggested:

B.java:

```
public class B extends Properties {

    public B() {
        setProperty("a", "aaa");
        setProperty("b", "bbb");
    }
}
```

C.java:

```
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.stringPropertyNames());
    }
}
```

The following output resulted the same, compiling with JDK 6, either using `-source 1.5` and/or `-target 1.5` or not.

Output on JVM 6:

```
[b, a]
```

Output on JVM 5:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: B.stringPropertyNames()Ljava/util/Set;
        at C.main(C.java:17)
```

So, why use `-source` and `-target` on compilation at all?

[This site](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javacexe.html) explains succinctly that you can use `-source` options to make the compiler fail if certain features of releases later than the specified are used. E.g., `-source 1.4` ensures you don't use generics (which would otherwise fail only at runtime).

The `-target` options is, according to the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), for enabling executing the compiled code on other (earlier) JVMs. E.g, if I use JDK 6 to compile my code but I need it to run on JVM 5, I'd use `-target 5` on compilation. If I don't, I'll get `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`.

I hope you're not overwhelmed by the answer ;)...

Comment: no, your answer was very good :-) So it makes no sense setting -target option higher than -source option?

Comment: You're right. No sense preventing usages of features from java release X (`-source X-1`) when the compiled code is designated to run on JRE X (`-target X`), that allows those features.